Why the timer stop after 1 second
using System.Collections;

using UnityEngine;

public class Timer : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ZeitManager zeitmanager;

    public IEnumerator TimerDownSekunden()
    {
        if (zeitmanager.Sekunden == 0)
        {

            zeitmanager.SekundenText.text = "" + zeitmanager.Sekunden;

            StartCoroutine(TimerDownMinuten());

        }

        zeitmanager.Sekunden--;

        zeitmanager.SekundenText.text = "" + zeitmanager.Sekunden;

        yield return StartCoroutine("TimerDownSekunden");

    }

    public IEnumerator TimerDownMinuten()
    {

        zeitmanager.Minuten--;

        zeitmanager.MinutenText.text = "" + zeitmanager.Minuten;

        zeitmanager.Sekunden = 60;

        zeitmanager.SekundenText.text = "" + zeitmanager.Sekunden;

        yield return StartCoroutine("TimerDownSekunden");

    }

}

I have a button this starts in the script Time Manager a function who call the IEnumerator off this script and it work but only for 1 Second after that the script just stops I checked it by having a TextMeshProUGUI update text on each run also I use a public int in Time Manager which I can see in the Unity Editor it works on the first run but then not anymore

Please read how to ask and edit this question to include more detail, or it may be closed. All you posted is a class. How are you using it? How do you know the timer stops after 1 second?

Don't change your title to say that the question was solved. Even though the old title was bad it at least hinted at the problem you had and could potentially help others find the question in the future (that the timer works perfectly now won't help anyone).

This script is for a timer that works really well
using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine;

using TMPro;

public class ZeitManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Sekunden;

    public int Minuten;

    public bool TimerLäuft;

    public TextMeshProUGUI SekundenText;

    public TextMeshProUGUI MinutenText;

    public void LevelStart()
    {

        TimerLäuft = true;

        StartCoroutine("TimerDownSekunden");

    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (Minuten == 0 && Sekunden == 0)
        {

            TimerLäuft = false;

        }

        if (Sekunden == 0 && TimerLäuft == true)
        {

            Sekunden = 60;

            Minuten--;

        }

        SekundenText.text = "" + Sekunden;

        MinutenText.text = "" + Minuten;


    }

    public IEnumerator TimerDownSekunden()
    {

        while(TimerLäuft == true)
        {

            Sekunden--;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);

        }
    }

}

I have now packed everything into a script and made it a little simpler and now everything works, I think it is the simplest timer possible
